# How did Gauss come up with his law?

Tags: electromagnetism, gauss

Why did it seem at the time of Gauss that the quantity we get by multiplication of electric field with the area would have some value to it? That is what was the motivation for Gauss to find the flux of the electric field. Even now the only reason I can think that why one would find it, is because it is something that is a 'natural' step for a theory of vector field to do. However, besides this, I have no physical motivation.

Comment: Gauss himself **may** have said something about it, basing his work on earlier work by Lagrange. Unfortunately I cannot find an English translation of this publication (in Latin): Carl Friedrich Gauss, "Theoria attractionis corporum sphaeroidicorum ellipticorum homogeneorum methodo nova tractata", *Commentationes societatis regiae scientiarium Gottingensis recentiores* **2**, 355–378 (1813) ([`archive.org` scan](https://archive.org/details/GaussC.F.1813TheoriaAttractionisCorporumSphaeroidicorumEllipticorumHomogeneorumM))

Comment: In the 1813 publication Gauss deals with gravity and gravitational fields (its title translates to: "The theory of the attraction of homogeneous spheroidal elliptic bodies treated by a new method"). Later he extended this to all attractive and repulsive forces obeying an inverse square law: C. F. Gauss, "Allgemeine Lehrsätze in Beziehung auf die im verkehrten Verhältnisse des Quadrats der Entfernung wirkenden Anziehungs- und  Abstossungs-Kräfte", pp. 1-51. In C.F. Gauss and W. Weber (eds.), *Beobachtungen des magnetischen Vereins im Jahre 1839.* Leipzig: Weidmann'sche Buchhandlung 1840.

Comment: The specific application to electromagnetism seems to originate in a 1861 publication by Maxwell: James Clerk Maxwell, "On Physical Lines of Force", Philosophical Magazine, Vols. 21 & 23 Series 4 (Parts I trough IV)

Comment: J.C. Maxwell, "On Physical Lines of Force. Part III. — The Theory of Molecular Vortices applied to Statical Electricity." *London, Edinburgh, and Dublin Philosophical Magazine and Journal of Science,* Vol. 23, Fourth Series, January-June, 1862,
[pp. 12-23](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Philosophical_Magazine/icM-AQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1) I am **not** a physicist. The relevant equations regarding Gauss's Law seem to appear on page 19, in particular equation (115)?

Comment: An English translation of the 1839 publication by Gauss is available: C. F. Gauss, "General propositions relating to attractive and repulsive forces acting in the inverse ratio of the square of the distance", In Richard Taylor (ed.), *Scientific memoirs, selected from the transactions of foreign academies of science and learned societies and from foreign journals Vol. 3*, London: R. & J.E. Taylor 1843, [pp. 153-196](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Scientific_Memoirs_Selected_from_the_Tra/qsY-AAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA153&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: @njuffa I might take some time and translate Gauss's 1813 publication, shouldn't take more than a month or so. The Latin seems straightforward, I just don't know how much time I'll be able to put into it

Comment: @Sam Gallagher Cool. I guess your Latin is better than mine then (I took five years of Latin in high school, decades ago). I won't be writing an answer to this question since I am not familiar with the subject matter and am not sure whether the bread crumbs I collected above accurately trace how Gauss's Law became applied to electromagnetism.

Comment: @njuffa I am certainly no latinist but I like the process of translation, especially 17th-19th texts, and I'm always looking for a new translation that can help people (and teach me more about old math and science as a bonus!)

Comment: Good news from the future, I've finished the translation of Gauss's *Theoria attractionis* (1813). Link: https://histomathsci.blogspot.com/2023/04/translation-of-gausss-theoria.html