# Resource recommendation for experiments that led to major concepts in physics

Tags: physics, experimental-physics, resource-recommendation

Any resource recommendations for history of physics giving special attention to experiments that led to certain concepts and theorems in physics? For example what led to the motivation of definition of torque or work energy theorem and so on.

I have asked several questions ([1](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/702983/motivation-for-the-definition-of-angular-momentum), [2](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/741591/330899) and [3](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/14637/16986)) but never got a satisfactory answer, thus this question.

Comment: I don't know of a book reference, but since there have been books written on "most important physics formulas", "most groundbreaking physics theories", "most historically significant physics results", etc. I would expect there to be at least one book focusing on the most significant physics experiments. Expanding beyond books (which your question actually does), maybe [this search](https://www.google.com/search?q=greatest+physics+experiments+of+all+time) will lead to something. If you find something really nice, and no one else provides anything better, maybe post your finding(s) as an answer.

Comment: See [Varvoglis, History and Evolution of Concepts in Physics](https://www.google.com/books/edition/History_and_Evolution_of_Concepts_in_Phy/mk_CBAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0). From back cover:"*This book explains how and why these changes occurred, through landmark experiments as well as theories that - for their time - were revolutionary.*"

Comment: @Conifold Thank you for the recommendation. These past few days I read the book and it was really good, having bits of really nice information here and there. However, about the moment of inertia (related to one of the questions mentioned in the post), I was only able to find that it was first introduced by Huygens. (1/2)

Comment: @Conifold This leads me to ask the question and receive some resources in the comments of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/746115/330899. As a side note, it was made painfully clear in the book how the second law of thermodynamics is not shown to be derived from anything more fundamental to date, something that was really new to me.

Comment: From what I understand, the [second law is derivable](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10690/65263) in statistical mechanics, but the derivation requires assumptions about the initial state. In other words, strictly speaking, it is not really a law, either fundamental or derivative, it is rather a consequence of a special initial state of the universe.